# What are the applications of spontaneous synchronization to engineering?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, modeling, computer-engineering

I came across the amazing phenomena of *spontaneous synchronization* and how it can be modelled by the Kuramoto Model. I am curious as to spontaneous synchronization has its relevance in engineering.

Apart from ensuring the safety of structures, could there also be applications in ares of data engineering and machine learning?

Comment: Piano tuning, where the two or three strings of each note are tuned very slightly differently so that they will adopt a slightly untempered tone with differing chords.

Answer (score 0):

#### Stick to physical things

Data and machine learning algorithms doesn't move in time with themselves.  Electrons in a computer will not exhibit the same phenomenon.

Comment: Electrons do synchronise spontaneously